# Remove the row from dataframe, that has string length greater than a certain number, after a certain character(",") till end

Tags: python, string, dataframe, split

**Input:** I have a dataframe with name containing 2 values divided by ","

```
id name
1  xy,ab
2  cv,asdf
3  piy,bs
```

**Expected Output:** I want to remove the row with name having string length greater than 2 after ",".

```
id name
1  xy,ab
3  piy,bs
```

Code I tried:

```
df = df[~df['name'].str.split().str.len().ge(2)]
df
```

This code only removes the string length greater than 2 but i want it to happen after ",".

Comment: Don't you want `.split(',')[1]`?  Or does that not work in a pandas chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Series.str.match` and pass the `regex`:

```py
>>> df[df['name'].str.match('.*?,\w{0,2}$')]

   id    name
0   1   xy,ab
2   3  piy,bs
```

Or you can just split the values on comma, take the last value, and check if length is less than or equals to 2:

```py
>>> df[df['name'].str.split(',').str[-1].str.len().le(2)]
   id    name
0   1   xy,ab
2   3  piy,bs
```

Comment: I don't know why but the regex method removed all the values. But the split one is working fine

Comment: That may be because the actual data is different than the sample data you have and regex can not match the pattern, because pattern is always written based on the data.

Comment: Now @ThePyGuy if my data is like:

`name
[ ['xy'] , ['ab'] ]
[ ['cv'] , ['asdf'] ]
[ ['piy'] , ['bs' , 'csx'] ]`

and I want to remove all the characters within quotes to be checked for length greater than 3. How will the code vary?

Comment: You mean both in `['bs' , 'csx']` not only the last one? If both, you may first want to explode the column then `df[df['name'].str.len().gt(3)]` and if the last one only, then only the split part will be gone, rest will be same, i.e. `df[df['name'].str[-1].str.len().gt(3)]`, because you already have the lists.

Comment: Thanks, i need to do for both after comma.